# When writing about a true court case. When should defense be capitalized?

Tags: grammar

**Example:** Christine returned to the defence council with my refusal of the offer to settle.

Comment: Check out these written instances of [*the defence suggests.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+defence+suggests%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) It seems to me almost half of them capitalise, and they're not obviously the *older* sources. But I would say it's a stylistic choice - one which I personally wouldn't make.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is best to capitalize it when it is a proper noun and not capitalize when it is not a proper noun.  Use the proper noun is when you are referring to the Defense as a collective entity of people.

> The Defense rests.
>   They mounted a defense on his behalf.
>   John Stuart, for the Defense. 
>   Our defense is an iron clad alibi.

As FumbleFingers points out above, this is not a hard and fast rule, rather a style point.  But, no one will fault you for following it.